# Django CMS multi-line field

Tags: django, django-cms

Is it possible to make multi-line field on this page, because it's really uncomfortable when you have to scroll to see the whole thing.

[image: How it looks like]

Comment: Is field `TextField` or `CharField`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils.html import linebreaks

class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'admin_your_field']

    def admin_your_field(self, obj):
        return linebreaks(obj.admin_your_field)
```

Comment: I guess I did something wrong, but it just added p tags in the &lt;p&gt; format